# Swing: How do I use multiple buttons?

Tags: java, swing, button

I created this little test program. It has 2 buttons and 2 labels. I want to know how I can use 2 buttons. So when I press button-1 then I change the text for text-1 and when I press button-2 then I change text for text-2. I just wanna get an idea of how I can use multiple buttons.

My code:

```
JLabel text1, text2;
JButton button1, button2;

public Game(String title) {
    super(title);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    addComponents();

    setSize(250, 250);
    setResizable(false);

}

public void addComponents() {
    text1 = new JLabel();
    getContentPane().add(text1, text2);

    text2 = new JLabel();
    getContentPane().add(text2);

    button1 = new JButton("Button");
    getContentPane().add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(this);

    button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    getContentPane().add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}
```

I'm new to programming, so I would also like if someone could write some comments for the code. Just so I get an idea on how the code for multiple buttons work.

Comment: @Tavo as this question is about "asking what the code does"  it is **off** topic on CR

Comment: @Tavo Code explanation is [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at Code Review.

Comment: EDIT: Y̶o̶u̶ ̶m̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶c̶o̶d̶e̶r̶e̶v̶i̶e̶w̶.̶s̶t̶a̶c̶k̶e̶x̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶.̶ Also, I fail to see how can you have written this code and not know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method you can get the source of the action

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if(e.getSource() == button1){
 //Do Something
}else if(e.getSource() == button2){
 //Do Something Else
}
```

Comment: When I write    if(e.getSource() == button1){  
Does that mean that when the button1 is pressed, then to the if statement?

Comment: Yes, the code inside if(e.getSource() == button1) is executed when button1 is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches to add listeners to buttons, here just a couple:

## Inner

If you don't have to do much actions in each button you can add inner listener in each button

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // DO STUFF

    }
});
```

## Common Listener

If you have more than 2 buttons (i guess your app will be bigger) you can use your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` and get source of the action

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if(source.equals(button1)){
        // DO STUFF    
    }
}
```

## Use `actionCommand` to clarify

To clarify this approach I would reccommend to use [`JButton.setActionCommand(stringCommand)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand(java.lang.String)) so after you can use a `switch`:

Declaring buttons:

```
button1.setActionCommand("command1");
button2.setActionCommand("command2");
```

In `ActionListener::actionPerformed()`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand();

    switch (command) {
    case "command1": 
        // DO STUFF FOR BUTTON 1
    break;
    case "command2": 
        // DO STUFF FOR BUTTON 2
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java 8, Lambdas could make the first variant much more concise: `button1.addActionListener(ae -> { System.out.println("called"); });`

Comment: @user140547 not using Java8 here, but feel free to add a new answer, it will help me and others ;)

Comment: What does this line mean? String command = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand(); You create a String called command and then? What does the rest mean? - I'm new to programming, so that's why I ask

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `setVisible(true)` before the components are added.

There are a few ways to deal with more elements in an ActionEvent:

- `e.getSource()` returns the object on which the event occurred. So, if button1 was pressed, `e.getSource()` will be the same as button1 (and `e.getSource()==button1` will thus be true)
- You can use separate classes for each ActionEvent. If you would add the ActionListener "Button1ActionEvent" [`button1.addActionListener(new Button1ActionEvent());`] you have to create this class, let it implement ActionListener and add the method actionPerformed as you had in your main class. Also, you can create a listener inside of the addActionListener-method [`button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // actionPerformed-method here });`]

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, its it much more concise to add ActionListeners:

```
button.addActionListener(ae -> System.out.println("foo"));
```

Using multiple statements:

```
button.addActionListener(ae -> { 
    System.out.println("foo");
    System.out.println("bar");
});
```